# Add Create in Version 2 of Django REST API Method

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a an API built in the Django rest-framework. The first version of a model didn't support post/create. I am now adding v2 of my API using the URL path method described [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/).

Here is my main URL router:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token
from board.urls import router

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/token/', obtain_auth_token, name='api-token'),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api/(?P<version>(1.0|2.0))/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Here is my project-specific URL router:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from . import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'sprints', views.SprintViewSet)
router.register(r'tasks', views.TaskViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
```

Here is my view:

```
class SprintViewSet(DefaultsMixin, viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.version == '2.0':
            return SprintSerializer2
        return SprintSerializer

    queryset = Sprint.objects.order_by('end')
```

My question is: how can I change from this read-only view to an update-able view based on the version?

I've thought about two approaches but I'm not sure how to do either...

One would be to route to a different view, but I'm not sure how to get the version from the included router.

The second would be to somehow tell Django that post/create is supported dynamically, based on the version.

[Note: this code is taken from an over-simplified tutorial, but expresses the problem I have in a more sophisticated application]

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here is to have different URL routes, instead of checking for a version flag.

e.g.

`api/sprints/<id>/get`
`api/v2/sprints/<id>/get`

where at the URL level you route to a different ViewSet for v1/v2

Comment: If I were to go that route, what is the right way to handle that, since the version number is in the beginning of the URL where the first router is looking, but I want make the switch in the more specific, included router?

Comment: so I was suggesting this way to do it http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/#urlpathversioning instead of trying to do namespaceversioning